# How can I set up patterns when using SequenceSplit?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence

Given a list

```
lst={0,0,0,0,0,"A1",0,0,0,"B2",0,0,"C3","D4","E5",0,0,0,"F6"}
```

how can I split it as

```
{{0,0,0,0,0},{"A1",0,0,0},{"B2",0,0},{"C3"},{"D4"},{"E5",0,0,0},{"F6"}}
```

I want to use `SequenceSplit`, but I don't know how to set up the right `pattern`.

```
SequenceSplit[lst, {_String} -> {}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Split[lst, Not @ StringQ @ #2 &]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"A1", 0, 0, 0}, {"B2", 0, 
>     0}, {"C3"}, {"D4"}, {"E5", 0, 0, 0}, {"F6"}}

```
SequenceSplit[lst, {s_String, a : Except[_String] ...} :> {s, a}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"A1", 0, 0, 0}, {"B2", 0, 
>     0}, {"C3"}, {"D4"}, {"E5", 0, 0, 0}, {"F6"}}

Comment: Very nice,Thanks! what do `#1` and `#2` mean in `Split` function?

Comment: @Jerry see [*Working with Pure Functions*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html) and [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)

Comment: kglr, do you have something against `!`? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you.

Comment: @Jerry, in a test function used as the second argument of `Split`, `#1` refers to the first element of a consecutive pair and `#2` to the second, See also [animation - Split](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Split.html) which illustrates how it works for  the default test function `SameQ`.

Comment: @kglr there's a little bug on dividing "C3" and "D4" when using `SequenceSplit` producing  {"C3","D4"}.

Comment: `SequenceSplit[lst, {s_String, a : Except[_String] ...} :> {s, a}]`, three `dot`s should be given after `Except`.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry; fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "A1", 0, 0, 0, "B2", 0, 0, "C3", "D4", "E5", 0, 0, 0, "F6"};

SequenceSplit[list, x : {_, 0 ...} :> x]
```

{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"A1", 0, 0, 0}, {"B2", 0,
0}, {"C3"}, {"D4"}, {"E5", 0, 0, 0}, {"F6"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "A1", 0, 0, 0, "B2", 0, 0, "C3", "D4", "E5", 0, 0, 0, "F6"};
```

An alternative is to use `SequenceCases`:

```
patts = {s_String, a : Except[_String] ...} | {a : Except[_String] ..} :> {s, a};

SequenceCases[lst, patts]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"A1", 0, 0, 0}, {"B2", 0,
> 0}, {"C3"}, {"D4"}, {"E5", 0, 0, 0}, {"F6"}}